# Check linked server database status registered in the DBConfig Database

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I am working with the Code below to check all the entries in the XXX Database of all the databases linked to the instance 
Server- XXX
DB _YYY
However when i run the Code, it throws an error i specified in the try - catch Statement ' Not connected' on the Status column.
I want the resuts to Display all the entries in the DBYYY and their Status 
Online, Offline. 
Example:

```
Server                   Database                    Status
AVYHSDBS                 Test                        Online
ANSDMDHDH                MDB                         Offline 
AHJDS                    SDB                         Not Connected
AHDGD                    KDB                         Could Not connect to Server
```

………
Can someone please help me here. thanks

My Code is below:

```
DECLARE @ABC SYSNAME
DECLARE @DEF SYSNAME
DECLARE @Status  NVARCHAR(100) 
DECLARE @DBState Table (DBName sysname, Status1 NVARCHAR(100)) 
DECLARE @remote_databases TABLE(Server sysname, Datenbank sysname, Status nvarchar(200))

DECLARE LinkedServersCur CURSOR FOR
         Select ABC, DEF from YYY
         Where GHI = 1; 
OPEN LinkedServersCur;
FETCH NEXT FROM LinkedServersCur INTO @ABC,@DEF
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
                    Execute sp_testlinkedserver @ABC    

                    Set @Status = (N'SELECT m.name, m.state_desc FROM [' +  @ABC)+ '].[master].[sys].[databases] m ' 
                    Insert into @DBState execute sp_executesql @status 

                    Insert into @remote_databases (Server, Datenbank, Status )
                    values (@ABC, @DEF, @status  )

                    select @ABC, DBName, status1 from @DBState
                    Delete from @remote_databases

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH 
                    Set @status = 'NOT CONNECTED ' 
                    Insert into @remote_databases 
                    Values (@ABC,@DEF, @Status) 
    END CATCH 

FETCH NEXT FROM LinkedServersCur INTO @ABC,@DEF

END
CLOSE LinkedServersCur;
DEALLOCATE LinkedServersCur

SELECT * FROM @remote_databases
Where Datenbank not in ( 'master' , 'tempdb' , 'model' , 'msdb' , 'DBConfig')
```

Comment: I did some tests and everything worked  correctly on my end. It is a bit unclear to me how to reproduce where it is going wrong on your end.

Comment: I suspect the execute sp_executesql stored proceedure is not available on my end

Comment: have you tried changing `execute sp_executesql@status` to `execute sp_executesql @status`. And removing can  `BEGIN CATCH can`

Comment: sorry the 'can' was a typo error .. ist not part of the Code

Comment: @Randi Vertrongen. I dont get the Change execute sp_executesql@status...to ….  it is the same  Change to what::…..

Comment: In the query in the question there is a space missing between `@status` and `sp_executesql` in the part: `...Insert into @DBState execute sp_executesql@status ....`. Might also be a typo but should be `...Insert into @DBState execute sp_executesql @status ....`

Comment: ok thanks. i tried it, but ist still not working

Comment: Have you isolated the content inside the try block to know exactly what line is triggering the error? Try to comment one line at a time and see when the error occurs.

Comment: @ronalldo yes i did, but all lines executed successfully.

Comment: Since you can see what server threw the error, have you tried to query that linked server specifically without the script (and dynamic query) to see if SQL Server throws a more specific error that could clarify what's the root cause of the error triggering the `catch`? Sorry for the delay, but you misspelled my user name and I wasn't notified of your answer.